# Custom ESLint rule fixer: Adding an import declaration if a helper function is not already imported

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I have a use case where I want to replace a variable function call, specifically something like `foo.value.toString()` to use a helper function `getStringValue(foo)`. I'm able to use the fixer to replace the text on the `CallExpression` node if I find it, so my rule fixer currently looks like this:

```
fixer => fixer.replaceText(node, `getStringValue(${identifierNode.getText()})`);
```

The issue with auto-fixing this error this way is that `getStringValue` may or may not already be imported into the file. I want this fixer to have the following behavior:

1. If the function is already imported into the file, do nothing else.
2. If the function is not imported, but its containing file module is, add this function to that module's imports.
3. If neither the function nor its containing file module are imported, import the module along with this function.

As far as I know from the [documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/extend/custom-rules#accessing-the-source-code), there's no easy way to get access to the root ESTree node using the `fixer` or `context` objects. The closest thing is `SourceCode.getText()`, which would mean I would have to parse the source text in order to resolve the imports - I would much rather interact directly with the entire AST. What's the best way to perform this automatic import procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is an easy way to extract the AST root node from the `context` object. It's located at `context.getSourceCode().ast`. I rewrote my fixer with the following logic:

```js
fixer => {
  fixer.replaceText(node, `getStringValue(${identifierNode.getText()})`);
  const body = context.getSourceCode().ast;
  const importDeclarations = body.filter(statement => statement.type === AST_NODE_TYPES.ImportDeclaration);
  ... // Check if the declaration has the import and add the appropriate imports if necessary
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be slightly unsafe here, you can assume that the user hasn't re-defined the `getStringValue` function locally in their file (generally a safe assumption if you own the codebase this rule is for).

In that case the best way to do this is by using selectors to inspect the imports, eg:

```
module.exports = {
  create(context) {
    let hasImport = false;
    let lastImport = null;
    return {
      ImportDeclaration(node) {
        lastImport = node;
        if (isImportICareAbout(node)) {
          hasImport = true;
        }
      },
      "My Selector For Other Linting Logic"(node) {
        // ...
        context.report({
          messageId: "myReport",
          fix(fixer) {
            const fixes = [
              fixer.replaceText(node, `getStringValue(${identifierNode.name})`),
            ];
            if (!hasImport) {
              const newImport = 'import { getStringValue } from "module";';
              if (lastImport) {
                // insert after the last import decl
                fixes.push(fixer.insertTextBefore(lastImport, newImport));
              } else {
                // insert at the start of the file
                fixes.push(fixer.insertTextAfterRange([0, 0], newImport));
              }
            }
            return fixes;
          },
        });
      },
    };
  },
};
```